# Insert or Update in DocumentDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to add a new player to a basketball team document in DocumentDb. Is it an INSERT or an UPDATE?

Say, the team document looks like this:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "Small Town Bobcats",
   players: [
      { id: 456, name: "John Smith", position: "Guard" },
      { id: 567, name: "James Green", position: "Center" }
   ]
}
```

Should this be a simple operation of replacing existing players with a new array that includes the new player's data? If not, what is the right approach to adding a new player to this team?

Answer (score 4):

There is no update in place in DocumentDB. You need to replace the document with a completely new one containing your updated player list.